# Python multi-process and parallel execution with result file writing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, rpy2

This is my R code.

```
resultFuntion<-function(var1,var2){
      path<-"/home/uvionicstech/Desktop/R_TENS/"
      source(paste(path,'rtest.R',sep=''))
      n<-1000
      value<-rnorm(n)
      sum=var1+var2
      rtest_out<-rtest(100,200)
      result<-value*sum*rtest_out
      return (result)
    }
```

**rtest---> function for adding 2 integers**

Trying to call this R function from python using rpy2 and written the result into separate files.

This is my python code.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import numpy as np
import time
from joblib import Parallel
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
var1=2
var2=31
output_location='/Desktop/pro1/'
path="/Desktop/R_TENS/"
def Analysis(var1,var2):
    r=ro.r
    r.source(path+"file.R")
    p=r.resultFuntion(var1,var2)
    filename1=str(i)+"output.txt"
    newfile=output_location+filename1
    with open (str(newfile),'w') as file:      
       file.write('result: %s for {}'.format(i) %(p))
    return p
    file.close()


threads=[]

for i in range(20):
    q = Queue()
    t1=Process(target=Analysis,name='thread{}'.format(i),args=(var1,var2))
    t1.start()
    Parallel(n_jobs=20, verbose=0,backend="threading")
    threads.append(t1)
    print('{} has started \n'.format(t1.name))

for i in threads:   # to know threads used
    i.join()
```

This process works in parallel. Because all files written at same time. Then i have tried with input as a json file and some other R function for some analysis reports. This file writing process takes very much time.So the advantage of parallel processing is not getting here.For writing 20 files it takes around 75 seconds. My new R function consists of many for loops. I have converted that in to foreach loop for parallel processing. But then my rpy2 library in python is not working properly.  Anybody knows that this method is not possible with json files?